# Don't print space after last value with iterator

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, set, range-based-loop

I'm having a problem with a beginner concept
in competitive programming extra space in print may cause wrong answer judgment
I want to iterate through a container like map or set but last value should not have a space

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> st = {1,2,3};
    for(auto x : st){
        cout<<x<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

why can't I do this

```
set<int> st = {1,2,3};
    for(auto x = st.begin(); st!=end();x++){
        if(x!=st.end()-2) cout<<x<<" ";
        else cout<<x;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard class templates `std::set` and `std::map` do not have random access iterators. So this expression

```
x!=st.end()-2
```

is invalid.

If you compiler supports C++ 20 then you may write for example

```
set<int> st = {1,2,3};
for( size_t i = 0; auto x : st){
    if ( i++ != 0 ) std::cout << ' ';
    cout << x ;
}
```

Or you could use a boolean variable instead of the variable `i` with the type `size_t`.

In any case you can declare the variable before the range-based for loop as for example

```
set<int> st = {1,2,3};
bool first = true;
for( auto x : st){
    if ( !first ) 
    { 
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        first = false;
    }   
    cout << x ;
}
```

If to use an ordinary for loop with iterators then you can write

```
for ( auto it = st.begin(); it != st.end(); it++)
{
    if ( it != st.begin() ) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the logical concept of the boolean variable? when it becomes true?

Comment: @Jee Initially before the first iteration it is set to true. And then after the first iteration of the loop it is equal to false.